# Match strings with fuzzy join where max 1 chr is different

Tags: r, string, character

Is there a way to detect if two strings have only 1 to 0 different characters?

Reproducable example:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)
  
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("howaryou", "hello", "summer", "goodbye"), y = c(1:4))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c("howareyou", "heelo", "summe", "goodbye"), z = c(66:69))

fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, match_fun = str_detect, by = "x")
      x.x y     x.y  z
1 howaryou 1    <NA> NA
2    hello 2    <NA> NA
3   summer 3   summe 68
4  goodbye 4 goodbye 69
```

I tried `str_detect` but this only works if the different chr is at the beginning or end ("summer" and "summe"). However, I would like to get

```
      x.x y     x.y    z
1 howaryou 1 howareyou 66
2    hello 2     heelo 67
3   summer 3     summe 68
4  goodbye 4   goodbye 69
```

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringdist` may be an option

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_left_join(df1, df2, by = 'x')
```

-output

```
#      x.x y       x.y  z
#1 howaryou 1 howareyou 66
#2    hello 2     heelo 67
#3   summer 3     summe 68
#4  goodbye 4   goodbye 69
```